# Microsoft Powerapps, Filter out based on column data

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerapps

I have a Powerapp pulling data from a SQL database.  The function on the Browser gallery is the following to return all entries:

```
SortByColumns(Search([@'[dbo].[orders]'], TextSearchBox1.Text, "name_last","contact_email","contact_sms","name_first"), "check_in", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

I need to filter in / out entries based on the following:

1. check_in is not Null AND
2. is_complete = 0

How can this be done with the code above?

Thanks for answering a n00b question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you are combining the [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) and [SortByColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-sort) in your example, you can also combine other functions, like [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup), in your expression, like in the example below:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter(
            [@'[dbo].[orders]'],
            !IsBlank(check_in),
            is_complete = 0),
        TextSearchBox1.Text,
        "name_last",
        "contact_email",
        "contact_sms",
        "name_first"),
    "check_in",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)))
```

Comment: Thanks I pasted it in and getting a "Unexpected characters" on the last ")".  Trying to play with it now.